# Aside from the Monero Stackexchange what else are good resources for learning about Monero?

Tags: monero-community

There are lots of good reading material on stackexchange just curious what else there is to read about this awsome cryptocurrency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a chat then your best resource is maybe [r/monero](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/), if you want to start running a node maybe go to the [monero website](https://getmonero.org/home), if you want the research papers leading up to Monero/another explanation of the tech then maybe you would like:

- The CryptoNote [whitepaper](https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf) :)
- The [RingCT](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1098.pdf) paper
- Some [slides](http://www.nicolascourtois.com/bitcoin/paycoin_privacy_monero_6.pdf) for extra bonus pictures and comparisons and stuff